# Do percentage calculation on solr facet for each bucket

Tags: solr, lucene

In solr, I am not able to calculate percentage of each bucket.

When I do faceting using solr with my data, I need to see the percentage of each bucket based on its parent bucket.

Lets say we have a data faceted as follows

```
{
    "facets": {
        "top_genres": {
            "buckets": [
                {
                    "val": "Fantasy",
                    "count": 1000,
                    "top_authors": {
                        "buckets": [
                            {
                                "val": "Mercedes Lackey",
                                "count": 500
                            },
                            {
                                "val": "Piers Anthony",
                                "count": 500
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "val": "Mystery",
                    "count": 1000,
                    "top_authors": {
                        "buckets": [
                            {
                                "val": "James Patterson",
                                "count": 250
                            },
                            {
                                "val": "Patricia Cornwell",
                                "count": 750
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Can I get the percentage of each buckets as follows,

```
{
    "facets": {
        "top_genres": {
            "buckets": [
                {
                    "val": "Fantasy",
                    "count": 1000,
                    "top_authors": {
                        "buckets": [
                            {
                                "val": "Mercedes Lackey",
                                "count": 500,
                                "p":50 // percentage distribution
                            },
                            {
                                "val": "Piers Anthony",
                                "count": 500
                                "p":50
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "val": "Mystery",
                    "count": 1000,
                    "top_authors": {
                        "buckets": [
                            {
                                "val": "James Patterson",
                                "count": 250,
                                "p":25
                            },
                            {
                                "val": "Patricia Cornwell",
                                "count": 750,
                                "p":75
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I am using solr 7.2. I am seeing few function to avg, sum etc. But seems not able to get the percentage one.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do it using built-in functionality. What I would suggest is either do it on the client side - e.g. take this JSON response, parse count field and calculate percentage the way you want.

The other option would be to write custom Solr [Component](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/7_2_0/solr-core/org/apache/solr/handler/component/SearchComponent.html), which would be included into the chain of components in solrconfig.xml. This would give you access to alter response. However, this would create need in keeping this custom jar during updates/migration of Solr itself and many other difficulties. 
For this simple task I would recommend to use first approach

Comment: thank you for that answer. One more question. But why would solr not include such an simple operation. Surely there must be a good reason behind it, which is not clear for starters like me.